# Problema com frequência na geração de um sitemap

Tags: html, sitemap

Tenho um *sitemap* que gerei de um site, exemplo `www.meusite.com.br/sitemap.xml`, gerei antes de colocar o site no ar.

Ele analisou todos os URLs do site e está tudo correto.

Quando o cliente cadastrar uma nova notícia no site, haverá mais uma URL nova no site, e eu não gostaria de gerar mais um *sitemap*.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: O título serve para descrever sucintamente **o problema**. Neste caso poderia ser o parágrafo onde você finalmente faz a pergunta. Sobre o que é a pergunta você coloca nas *tags* e talvez na descrição da pergunta. E "dúvida" é desnecessário, você só posta algo aqui quando tem uma dúvida, problema, precisa de ajuda. Então essas palavras são redundantes sempre.

Comment: Está certo, corrigi.

Comment: Aproveite para ver como fica as edições dos outros usuários para ver como deixar a sua pergunta mais fácil de ler e conseguir melhores respostas. O que eu posso dizer sobre o problema é que só criando um *script* ou usar uma ferramenta pronta executada de tempos em tempos ou manualmente ou ainda automaticamente após um *upload* que verifique a estrutura e gera o *sitemap*. Mesmo assim não sei se ficaria bom, não é fácil criar algo que identifique tudo o que deve ou não ser colocado no *sitemap*. Mas sei lá, mudar o *sitemap* deve ser menos de 1% do tempo gasto na maioria das manutenções.

Comment: Um script pode ser o ideal, tem algum modelo?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [EasySiteMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasySiteMap) para gerar o novo sitemap.xml, ele inclusive gera o index também caso mais de um arquivo site map seja necessários.

Eu utilizo com o [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) e ele gera de tempo em tempo. Mas você pode criar uma rotina com ele e executa-la no evento que achar melhor.